Ho to use Dynamic Parameters in a none direct mode query
I want to use, in power query with M language, the selected value of a slicer created in Power BI.
I need to do it in a import mode query.
I think it is only possible in a direct mode query, if so, what is the best way to do it if it is possible in a import mode query?
Thanks in advance
José

Why do you want to do this in import mode? Just load full data set and slice it. Is it very huge?

I want the selected value to include it in the URL of a API Call in Power Query

I think the only way is to create a parameter in Transform data mode and enable its load to model. Then user will have opportunity to change it through menu in Report mode and you can show the value of this parameter in some visual. But there is no opportunity to change such a parameter by visual (slicer). You can also change such parameter in the report published in pbi service but it's quite tricky.
